# How do you run a long PHP script and keep sending updates to the browser via HTTP?

Tags: php, scripting, timing, updates

How do you run a long PHP script and keep sending updates to the browser via HTTP?

Something to do with output buffering but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: PHP is not made for long run. Why do you need it?

Comment: Yes what purpose you need it ? Making some streaming service or what ?
If want to update browser with info use " AJAX " then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output Buffering is thinking in the right direction, you start output buffering with `ob_start()` just like you would with sessions (`session_start`) somewhere in the top of your script, before any output is sent.

Then, you can use `ob_flush` and `flush` to keep flushing the output. For example, if you are in a `foreach` loop and at the end of each loop you want to output the new row and wait 1 second you would can do that.

But also look at `set_time_limit`, because otherwise people might experience a timeout after 30 seconds or so.

Another quick note, some browsers require a minimum number of bytes of output before they actually start showing it. I'm not sure what amound of bytes it was, I think it was around the 4000. Also, some browsers won't render certain elements (like tables) until they are closed. So flushing won't work there either.

Comment: "some browsers require a minimum number of bytes" -- Firefox included? You mean this technique of sending updates via HTTP doesn't really update users as stuff is done on the server?

Comment: I'm not sure which browsers behaved like that of the top of my head, I can tell you that in my experience and opinion this technique is not the best / most effective / reliable one. Let's just say that if you are able to use Javascript I would definitely pick that over this solution, personally.

Comment: I have tested some code on Firefox, and it updates *without needing 4K bytes*, but you have to ensure that you end any open elements (within `<body>`) else it won't display, and you have to enclose outputted text in an element (such as a `<p>`)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like what you are after:

> output buffering, PHP sends the output of your scripts to your web server as soon as it's ready - this might be line by line or code block by code block.

[Output Buffering](http://www.linuxformat.co.uk/wiki/index.php/PHP_-_Output_buffering)

> The ob_start() function is used to
>   create a new output buffer, and you
>   can immediately start writing to it by
>   printing out content as normal. Once
>   you have a buffer open, there are two
>   ways to close it: ob_end_flush() and
>   ob_end_clean(), both of which end the
>   buffer, but do so in slightly
>   different ways. The former ends the
>   buffer and sends all data to output,
>   and the latter ends the buffer without
>   sending it to output, effectively
>   wiping out any information you saved
>   in there. Every piece of text
>   outputted while an output buffer is
>   open is placed into that buffer as
>   opposed to being sent to output.
>   Consider the following script:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  print "In first buffer!\n";
  ob_end_flush();
  ob_start();
  print "In second buffer!\n";
  ob_end_clean();
  ob_start();
  print "In third buffer!\n";
?>
```

> That script will output "In first
>   buffer" because the first text is
>   placed into a buffer then flushed with
>   ob_end_flush(). The "In second buffer"
>   won't be printed out, though, because
>   it's placed into a buffer which is
>   cleaned using ob_end_clean() and not
>   sent to output. Finally, the script
>   will print out "In third buffer"
>   because PHP automatically flushes open
>   output buffers when it reaches the end
>   of a script.

Comment: Will the browser display flushed output without waiting for the whole HTML page to download? coz when I do this the browser waits for the whole page to finish ...

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a kind of background task, and an interface giving you the progress rate.

for instance, a page called job.php

```
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<100; ++$i)
    {
       store($i);
       // long stuff
       sleep(42);
    }
?>
```

and progress.php

```
<?php
      return get($i);
?>
```

Then some ajax calls to progress.php?task=mytaskid and update the GUI. I have seen such method for a "big" file upload and found it great.

Edit: sorry, this doesn't exactly respond the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
# try this...
for (;;) {
  echo time() . '<br>';
  ob_flush(); # http://php.net/ob_flush
  flush(); # http://php.net/flush
  sleep(1); # http://php.net/sleep
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it the page updating using simple HTTP outputting, to make it work:

- Ensure that you close any open elements within `<body>` - else it won't display
- Enclose outputted text in an element (such as a `<p>`)
- Use output buffering & normal flushing
- Tested on Firefox 3

Here is my code:

```
for ($nc=0; $nc<10; $nc++){

    // delay just to test
    sleep(1);

    // send message to browser
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    echo "<p>Update ".$nc."</p>";
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
}
```