# allow PHP script with long execution time to send updates back to the browser

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I looked over a few of the questions, namely

- [Show progress for long running PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049303/show-progress-for-php-long-script)
- [How do you run a long PHP script and keep sending updates to the browser via HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996088/how-do-you-run-a-long-php-script-and-keep-sending-updates-to-the-browser-via-htt)

and neither one seems to answer my question, part of which seems to be "how do I do this?" and the other half is "Hey, the way I'm doing this right now - is it the best way?  Could I code this better?"

I have a simple ajax script that sends some data over to a PHP script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'analysis.php',      
    data: { reportID:reportID, type:type, value:value, filter_type:filter_type, filter_value:filter_value, year:year },        
    success:function(dataReturn){          
      analysis_data = JSON.parse(dataReturn);
      /* do stuff with analysis_data... */
});
```

This PHP script takes about 3 minutes to run, as it loops through a database and runs some pretty complex queries:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);

$breaks = [ 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 99999999 ];
$breaks_length = count($breaks);
$p = 0;

foreach ( $breaks as $b ) {

  $p++;
  $percentage_complete = number_format($p / $breaks_length,2) . "%";

  $sql = "query that takes about 20 seconds to run each loop of $b....";  

  $query = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
  while(odbc_fetch_row($query)){   
    $count = odbc_result($query, 'count');
  }

  $w[]  = $count;

  /* tried this... doesn't work as it screws up the AJAX handler success which expects JSON
  echo $percentage_complete;
  ob_end_flush();
  */
}

echo json_encode($w);
?>
```

All of this works - but what I'd really like to do is find a way after each `foreach` loop, to output `$percentage_complete` back to the user so they can see it working, instead of just sitting there for 2 minutes with a FontAwesome icon spinning in front of them.  I tried using `ob_start();`, but not only does it not output anything until the page is done running, it echoes the value, which is then part of what is sent back to my AJAX success handler, causing it to screw up.  (I need the output in a JSON_encoded format as I use it for something else later.)

So far in threads I've read, my only thought is to start the `$breaks` array loop on the previous page, so instead of looping 6 times on the same page, I loop once, return an answer, then call `analysis.php` again using the second element of the `$breaks` array, but I'm not sure this is the best way to go about things.

Also - during the 3 minutes that the user is waiting for this script to execute, they cannot do anything else on the page, so they just have to sit and wait.  I'm sure there's a way to get this script to execute in such a way it doesn't "lock down" the rest of the server for the user, but everything I've searched for in Google doesn't give me a good answer for this as I'm not sure exactly what to search for...

Comment: You did json_encode($percentage_complete), right?  You have nothing else in the JS callback except "do_stuff"?

Comment: Typically the callback would parse whatever is handed back to it and replace the innerHTML of some element on the page where you wanted the feedback to be displayed....

Comment: The question isn't about how to handle the actual json response that the PHP page is giving back to the success call - it's a long section of code that I run in the success call to handle it, and it works fine.  The question is whether or not there is any way for me, while the script is in the process of executing, to return something to the user so they can see progress happening in "real time" - and @Kkinsey, I tried outputting it as json - and while I could get it to work, it didn't output anything until the script had completely finished (which is meaningless to me...)

Comment: Does this help?  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/show-progress-report-for-long-running-php-scripts.html

Comment: Alternatively looking for `readyState==3` might do the trick: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/php/ajax-progress-php-script-without-polling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering what is know as [Session Locking](http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/). So basically PHP will not accept another request with `session_start()` until the first request has finished.

The immediate fix to your issue is to remove `session_start();` from line #1 completely because I can see that you do not need it.

---

Now, for your question about showing a percentage on-screen:

**analysis.php (modified)**

```
<?php
ob_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);

$breaks = [ 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 99999999 ];
$breaks_length = count($breaks);
$p = 0;

foreach ( $breaks as $b ) {

  $p++;

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['percentage_complete'] = number_format($p / $breaks_length,2) . "%";
  session_write_close();

  $sql = "query that takes about 20 seconds to run each loop of $b....";  

  $query = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
  while(odbc_fetch_row($query)){   
    $count = odbc_result($query, 'count');
  }

  $w[]  = $count;

  /* tried this... doesn't work as it screws up the AJAX handler success which expects JSON
  echo $percentage_complete;
  ob_end_flush();
  */
}

echo json_encode($w);
```

**check_analysis_status.php** get your percentage with this file

```
<?php
session_start();
echo (isset($_SESSION['percentage_complete']) ? $_SESSION['percentage_complete'] : '0%');
session_write_close();
```

Once your AJAX makes a call to `analysis.php` then just call this piece of JS:

```
// every half second call check_analysis_status.php and get the percentage
var percentage_checker = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check_analysis_status.php',
        success:function(percentage){
            $('#percentage_div').html(percentage);

            // Once we've hit 100% then we don't need this no more
            if(percentage === '100%'){
                clearInterval(percentage_checker);
            }
        }
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: I'm definitely using session variables in here, but I can easily call those from the previous page and pass them in my ajax POST section.  Thank you though for taking so much time to answer this question!  I really appreciate it!  Let me work through everything in here, there's a lot to read.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this a couple different ways, but the pattern I like the best is to have three scripts (or one controller to handle all of this), `analysis_create.php`, `analysis.php`, and `analysis_status.php`. The key is to create a DB object that you reference in your status checks (`analysis_status.php`). `analysis_create.php` will store all the data in the post into a DB table that will also have a column for `percent_complete`. The `analysis_create.php` function should return an ID/Token for the `analysis`. Once the front-end has the ID, it would post to `analysis.php` and then after a delay (250ms) kill the request, because you don't want to wait for it to finish. `analysis.php` should read the data out of the DB and start doing the work. You will need to make sure `ignore_user_abort` is set properly in your `analysis.php` script. Once the request to `analysis.php` is killed, you will start long polling to `analysis_status.php` with that ID. As `analysis.php` is working through the query, it should be updating the corresponding DB record with the percentage complete. `analysis_status.php` should look up this record and return the percentage complete to the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. What caused it is different to what people are suggesting here.

Reason was gzip was enabled. Leading to a type of session locking even without an actual session.

Several ways to disable for one specific file:
[How to disable mod_deflate in apache2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922934/how-to-disable-mod-deflate-in-apache2)

Put this in httpd.conf

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI getMyFile\.php$ no-gzip dont-vary
```